# Every time i try to install a new package i get gyp err syntax error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass, yarnpkg

I was installing firebase, before this I tried installing yarn add react-router-dom, this same thing happened  I had to create new project and copy all files again to new project , one thing I noticed
was this happened after adding the project to github, before I added the project to the github repository, if i installed any packages, I didn't get any error,

```
$ yarn add firebase
yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⠄ node-sass
[-/4] ⠄ waiting...
[-/4] ⡀ waiting...
error C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Muhammad\\Desktop\\React projects\\szone-shoppee-project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.5.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python38\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python38\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:333:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Muhammad\\Desktop\\React projects\\szone-shoppee-project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Muhammad\Desktop\React projects\szone-shoppee-project\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

Comment: What is your `node-sass` version? only version 5.0 or higher is supported on `node v15`. Please refer to the link below [node-sass#node-version-support](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1918

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of these two things.

1. Downgrade Python to 2.x.
2. Install the packages using npm install --ignore-scripts

NOTE: This will cause npm to stop running scripts defined in the package.json

Comment: I solved the issue, but the approach was different, here's what I did - 1st I removed node-sass, then I added firebase, and re-installed node-sass and it worked! everytime node-sass is getting in conflict with all other packages while i try to install.